# Force BootCamp to use GPT

Tags: bootcamp, windows, disk-utility, dual-boot, diskutil

I have installed BootCamp manually to the last partition on my SSD `/dev/disk0s13`. It works, no problems, but every time I manage my partitions from OS X (or any other OS that is not Windows), the computer creates a new hybrid MBR, which makes Windows unbootable because it can’t find the Windows partition. I have to manually remove hybrid MBR via `gdisk` every time I manage my partitions.

I have a MacBook Pro 2015 13" Model with 512 GBs of storage and has 6 Operating Systems installed on it. I have macOS High Sierra and OS X Yosemite installed. I mostly use High Sierra.

Is there any possible way to either stop OS X from creating hybrid MBR or force Windows to use GPT? *By the way, I'm using Bitlocker, not sure if it makes a difference.*

**UPDATE 1:** I was trying to reproduce hybrid MBR with Disk Utility, and I discovered Disk Utility no longer produces that problem. Not sure about GParted.

Comment: Windows is supposed to be using GPT, but for some reason it's confused when there is a hybrid MBR and is not able to find the Windows partition, therefore not booting up.

Comment: What you need to post is an example where the conversion to hybrid partitioning occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have hybrid partitioning, then Windows will only see the partitions defined in the MBR table. There is no workaround for this. High Sierra removes hybrid partitioning in favor of a fully protected MBR. Yosemite can convert to hybrid, especially if partitions 2, 3 and/or 4 in the GPT are type `EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7`.

> Note: Type `EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7` will appear as `Microsoft Basic Data` in output from `diskutil list`.

Comment: I can confirm that my disk’s 3rd partition is Microsoft Basic Data.